# IBAction does not have a sound and animation , swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, viewdidload

I wanted to add sound and animation to button, but, it doesn't work, for example :

```
@IBAction func retry(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    buttonBeep?.play()
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "retryTwo.png")!, forState: .Highlighted)
    self.viewDidLoad()
}
```

My question is why it automatically jumps to `viewDidLoad` and  does not comply first two line? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't call `viewDidLoad()`! Where did you read that you have to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first line doesn't get executed because buttonBeep is nil, so unwrapping the optional produces nil and the method is not called. 
For the second line, I think you firstly need to cast sender object, and then call setImage. 
You also have a typo at "sorState: .Highlighted", it is "forState"

What is the type of sender? Where is buttonBeep initialized?

Comment: buttonBeep is initalized in class ViewController,  as var buttonBeep : AVAudioPlayer? it works in different buttons, so I dont know why it doesn't work in this.

Comment: Do you call prepareToPlay() before play() ?